# What is an "empty" key or effect in Kubernetes tolerations?

Tags: kubernetes

In [taint and toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) the docs say:

> Note: There are two special cases:
>
> An empty `key` with operator `Exists` matches all keys, values and effects
> which means this will tolerate everything.
>
> An empty `effect` matches all effects with key `key1`.

By "empty" does it mean set to `""` or not present in the YAML? Is there a difference?

Also, what's going on with "`key1`", does it mean key literally set to the value `key1`?